# How do I make my Html Image Source from a file path?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to insert an image from my computer into my HTML page (hopetnorman.pythonanywhere.com) and it's not working. Here is the code:

```
<img src="C:\Users\Alan\Downloads\Thomas Logo\Dogo.jpg" height="50px" class="Barpic">
```

Anybody know why?

Comment: are you sure that the filename is correct? Can you copy the complete path into the browser and get the image displayed? More often than not, a typo is the source of the error.

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly from the File

Comment: Its from my computer

Comment: if you want to see it at hopetnorman.pythonanywhere.com you need to load it on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way - 
I posted it on imgur then copied the image address from there.

Comment: Glad you could solve it. Can you mark the answer of Kagemaru or your own as the solution so that this question is no longer "unanswered"? (there is a checkmark left of each answer to mark an answer as the solution or the most helpful one.)

Comment: are images posted on imgur permanent? Because if not, you propably get problems if imgur is offline, changes the image url format or simply removes your image

Comment: "As of February 2015, Imgur now states that images are never deleted unless requested"  - They shouldn't be deleted but if they go offline then that might cause problems. I'll have to look into that.Thanks.

Comment: I am looking forward as to which answer you will select as the solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me, like you're trying to put a local file into a hosted page. This would not work, because the hosted page does not know where `"C:\"` is.

For it to work on a hosted website, you need to upload it from your computer to the page, or at a service that hosts your pictures and use the path to that online picture to your html site.

It would need to look something like this:

```
<img src="http://hopetnorman.pythonanywhere.com/Thomas%20Logo/Dogo.jpg" height="50px" class="Barpic" />
```

Or if the picture lies in the same folder as your page.

```
<img src="./Dogo.jpg" height="50px" class="Barpic" />
```

Also for code posts, there is a button `"{}"` while editing.

Comment: I may seem stupid - I have no idea what you mean (i'm  2  months new to html) Could you phrase your answer as if you were talking to a baby 2 months old?

Comment: Did you upload the image and put it next to your html page?

Comment: I uploaded it, went to files, copied the path, and pasted into the image source

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way will be if you put your image into folder where you have your html file then:

```
<img src="Dogo.jpg" height="50px" class="Barpic">
```

Or make another folder in folder where your html is for all your images:

```
<img src="folderWhereIhaveHTML/folderForImages/Dogo.jpg" height="50px" class="Barpic">
```

Comment: my website is not in a file on computer - it is an online site - pythonanywhere

Comment: anything i found is that your file source should look like
    src = "http://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/myusername/files/home/myusername/picture.png"

Ofc it depends on where did u uploaded it. Sooo its just have to be path from web not from your computer. Sorry if im wrong! I have never used hosting websides ;p